# Field has incomplete type const char * []

Tags: c++

I am trying tot pass argv from the main function of my program to the constructor of my class. I want to then set a field in my class to those values. I have  `const char * _argv[];` in my header file. My constructor is:

`Sweeper(int argc, const char * argv[]){_argc = argc; _argv = argv;}`

What do I need to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For function parameters (only), `const char * argv[]` is a funny way of spelling `const char **argv`. So the fix is to define `_argv` to match.

Comment: The problem with that is getopt_long() doesn't like const char ** for some reason.

Comment: `getopt_long` takes a `char *const *`, not a `char const **`.

Comment: @Joe: better would be to accept it as a `char * const *` or `char **` in the first place, if you can.

Comment: @JoeTyman, Casting is very, very rarely a good solution to make your problem disappear.

Comment: @SteveJessop I just cast the `char const **` to `char * const*` I change my field to a `char const **`

Comment: @chris: although beware that unless POSIXLY_CORRECT is set, GNU `getopt_long` itself casts away the const on its argv parameter and mutates the array. The type of that parameter is a bit of a sorry story IIRC, although I can't find a full explanation to remind myself and link to.

Comment: @SteveJessop, Good to know FFR; I've never used `getopt_long`.